# DataTrigger using Storyboard animation does not always execute. However setting Property without annimations does execute

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, visual-studio-2015

**The CommandLine.Success trigger does not always execute the associated storyboard.**

However, if I apply a property setter instead of a storyboard, then I observe trigger execution every time.

I am using **( VS20015 Developer Preview ).**
I am concluding this behavior as a defect.

The storyboard that represents a failure gets executed consistently. However, the storyboard that represents a success does not always get triggered. When I replace the success storyboard with just a property setter, then the property gets updated every time.

```
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxCommandStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static consolePackage:CommandStatus.Succeeded}">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandSucessfulStory}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static consolePackage:CommandStatus.Failed}">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandFailedStory}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Now, if I replace the success storyboard to be triggered with just a property setter, then the datatrigger will get executed every time.

```
    <Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static consolePackage:CommandStatus.Failed}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Source code: [Holoware](https://github.com/bizmonger/Holoware)

Comment: Are `CommandSucessfulStory` storyboard modifying the same property that `CommandFailedStory`?

Comment: Yes. They are operating on the same property

Comment: Check my answer, I hope it helps you. A mark/up vote is really apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very sure the problem is because you need to use the [StopStoryboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stopstoryboard(v=vs.110).aspx) before `BeginStoryboard`.

So, the Style resource should look similar to:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxCommandStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static consolePackage:CommandStatus.Succeeded}">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bSbFailed"/>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bSbSucessful" Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandSucessfulStory}"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static consolePackage:CommandStatus.Failed}">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bSbSucessful"/>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bSbFailed" Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandFailedStory}"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Partial XAML code (using the same objects name):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <consolePackage:StatusClass x:Name="GridDataContext"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="CommandSucessfulStory">
            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" >
                <ColorAnimation To="Green" Duration="00:00:0.025"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="CommandFailedStory">
            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" >
                <ColorAnimation To="Red" Duration="00:00:0.025"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Storyboard>

        <Style x:Key="TextBoxCommandStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static consolePackage:CommandStatus.Succeeded}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bSbFailed"/>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bSbSucessful" Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandSucessfulStory}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static consolePackage:CommandStatus.Failed}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bSbSucessful"/>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="bSbFailed" Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandFailedStory}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBox Text="---TARGET TEXT---" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxCommandStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Nested classes:

```
public class StatusClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _status;
    public string Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            if (string.Equals(_status, value))
                return;

            _status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }

    public StatusClass()
    {
        _status = CommandStatus.Failed;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class CommandStatus
{
    public static readonly string Succeeded = "SucceededValue";
    public static readonly string Failed = "FailedValue";
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: @ScottNimrod let me know the results.

Comment: No. It did not work for me. I get a runtime error on my property changed event when I attempt your suggestion.

Comment: Please, submit the error description and if possible the inner exception.

Comment: 'CommandSucessfulStory' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Style'.

Comment: @ScottNimrod the issue is in your original code. You need to check this `<Storyboard x:Key="CommandSucessfulStory">` (set a value to Storyboard x:Key tag).